# Overriding GeoNode template?

Tags: geonode

I´m making a GIS-Portal with GeoNode 2.6 (running in ubuntu 16.04 server) and I want to change the look of the home page following this instructions: http://docs.geonode.org/en/master/tutorials/admin/customize_lookfeel/customize/theme_admin.html (I´m a beginner at this). I have copied the "site_index.html" and "site_base.html" from 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geonode/contrib/geosites/site_template/templates/
to
/etc/geonode/templates/
I edited both html files.
Then I run the collectstatic command and restart apache2, but i see no changes in the homepage.

in local_settings.py is set:

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/etc/geonode/templates',
    os.path.join(GEONODE_ROOT, 'templates')

Any ideas of what i´m missing to make it work?

I also tried editing the index.html file without any luck. It only changes when editing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geonode/templates/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i did it following [this setup steps](http://docs.geonode.org/en/2.4.x/tutorials/admin/customize_lookfeel/customize/setup_admin.html)

Following the previus link you will create a project folder in home/geonode/my_geonode. Editions made here will be displayed in the web page.

In order to override the html files, complete blocks must be copied to site_base and site_index, and then edited.

Also check the tips in [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259546/customize-geonode-after-a-quick-install/261026#261026) ´s answer to make sure your overriding files are located in the right place

Answer (score 2):

If you following the installation steps like below, it should work out of the box:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:geonode/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install geonode
```

Then set the IP address and create a superuser.

```
geonode createsuperuser
sudo geonode-updateip 127.0.0.1
```

Then you can open & browse the site http://127.0.0.1

Once that works, you can start some makeup. Does that not work for you?

Comment: The installation did work fine, displaying the default GeoNode webpage. the problem was trying to change the look of the web page. Now I found how and post the answer. Thanks.