# GeoNode 2.6 template overriding

Tags: geonode

I have a fresh installation of GeoNode 2.6 on Ubuntu 16.04. The Web site is accessible, however, we are experiencing issues with the "template-overriding" feature.

I'm aware of [GeoNode 2.6 problem template overriding](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/243682/91064).

I have read the doc about ["theming" GeoNode](http://docs.geonode.org/en/latest/tutorials/admin/customize_lookfeel/customize/theme_admin.html). (I could have missed something though, feel free to point it out if that's the case)

From my understanding if I put my HTML sources in /etc/geonode/templates they should override the default sources (that's the behaviour I'm seeking) and the page should update automatically. However that does not seem to be the case. In fact nothing happens (apparently) when I do the latter. I even tried executing the following commands to no avail.

```
geonode collectstatic
service apache2 restart
```

My local_settings.py seem all right

```
GEONODE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(geonode.__file__)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
'/etc/geonode/templates',
os.path.join(GEONODE_ROOT, 'templates'),
)

# Additional directories which hold static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    '/etc/geonode/media',
    os.path.join(GEONODE_ROOT, 'static'),
]
```

Is it possible use my templates by putting them in /etc/geonode/templates (as mentioned here) in order to theme GeoNode?

If possible how can that be done ?

If not possible, why is it not?

Comment: What you did used to work fine in 2.4 version. 2.6 seems to work differently. The -"Theming" Geonode- link you posted is the third part of a series of instructions. Have you read the first two parts?. Overriding works fine creating a Geonode project and editing in the project folder.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've done as the section you point out says but I'm still having issues. The changes on the pages doesn't show...

Comment: Do you have any idea what I could have done wrong?

Comment: I tell you what works form me, maybe it helps: I followed the instruction in http://docs.geonode.org/en/latest/tutorials/install_and_admin/geonode_install/setup_configure_httpd.html#setup-configure-httpd then, the file I edit is in this location: /home/geonode/my_geonode/my_geonode/templates/site_index.html . Edition must be in whole blocks, I copy complete blocks from original files and then edit. To see changes sometimes i have to empty cache, since the browser reads from the cached instead of the new edited file.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I had some issues with geoserver's location but the website is now accessible.