# Customize GeoNode after a quick install

Tags: geonode

I've install GeoNode through `apt-get install geonode`. As per the [Quick Installation Guide](http://docs.geonode.org/en/latest/tutorials/install_and_admin/quick_install.html).
After such installation how do one customize the pages ? I don't seem to find any indication reading the doc on how it should be done.

I followed the instructions at [Setup & Configure HTTPD](http://docs.geonode.org/en/latest/tutorials/install_and_admin/geonode_install/setup_configure_httpd.html#setup-configure-httpd) and I'm having some issues customizing.
The changes made in `site_index.html` don't show up when I visit the home page.

Am i obligated to create a project as per [GeoNode (v2.6) installation on Ubuntu](http://docs.geonode.org/en/latest/tutorials/install_and_admin/geonode_install/index.html) ?

Any advice would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same installation and it works fine in GeoNode 2.6.3. It´s important that you edit the file in the correct path: `/home/geonode/geonode/geonode/templates/site_index.html` (or whatever name you put to your project instead of "geonode").
Also check your `wsgi.py` file, that it´s pointing to your GeoNode project:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "your_geonode_project_name.settings")
```

NOTE: by only changing back to `geonode.settings` in this file you can change the whole theme from your-project-theme to the default one.

It is not necessary to restart Apache to see these changes, but depending on your browser you might have to empty the cache.
If you edited the CSS files, run the `collectstatic` command to see changes.
All template files you want to edit should be copied first to the above path in the same location they are in /etc/geonode/templates. For example: if you want to edit the layer_details.html file, which is in `/etc/geonode/templates/layers/`, copy the file to `/home/geonode/geonode/geonode/templates/layers/layer_detail.html` and edit this one (it´ll override the first one). You can edit straight in the `/etc/geonode` but you will have a better organized GeoNode project if you work on your GeoNode project folder, and you also keep a backup 0km file if you ever need it.

Comment: I have deployed the website successfully. Thanks very much for you help. I appreciate it. I'm accepting you answer as that's the procedure that I used.